# Is there a way to check for direct update from native - IBM Mobilefirst?

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to implement Direct Update in my app. In my app, I have display the native page as home page.

So from wlcommoninit(), I am calling WL.Nativepage.show(), to move to native page.

Before moving to native page, I want my app to check for direct update. So before calling WL.Nativepage.show(), I have called the below API,

> WL.Client.CheckforDirectUpdate()

It is working like this,

1. App loads
2. Check for direct update
3. Direct update available - so default dialog shows to update the app
4. In the background, the app is moving to native page.

I want the app to move to the home page only if there is no update available,
so in onSuccess method of WL.Client.CheckforDirectUpdate(), I am passing to the native page.

In some cases the app works perfect, but some times once the update dialog displays to the user the app is moving to the native page and the dialog disappears again I have to return to any hybrid page to access the update dialog.

So I would like to check for notification in the home page [Native Page]. Is there any equivalent native[Android and IPhone] Mobilefirst API available for direct update?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API. However perhaps you could use the SendAction API to invoke JS code and return the result. I don't think this will play out as expected, though: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_action_sender.html